# How Do I Set Analysis Services' AllowedBrowsingFolders Property to Include Subdirectories?

Tags: ssas

The folder browser in SSAS is limited to folders that are explicitly listed in the server's AllowedBrowsingFolders property. For example, when I use the Restore Database dialog box, I can only see the folders I've listed in the property setting, not their subdirectories.

I'm lazy and don't want to have to add every new directory I create to the property.  Is there any way to set the property at a parent level and include the subdirectories?
I've tried using variations on DOS wildcards ( e.g. E:\SqlData\Olap\ *) but can't find one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entering the full path like "D:\OLAP" will let you browse any directory under that or if you want to browse the entire drive just enter "D:\".

If you need multiple paths make sure to use the pipe char as a separator. e.g. "C:\|D:\"
If your still unable to browse sub directories I would look at permissions of the account your using to run SSAS.